# How to stop count from duplicating partials in #show?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

For some reason I am getting duplicates of `show.html.erb`. The duplicates happen to coincide with what the `.count` is, even if I remove `.count` from the show file.

**users/show.html.er**b

```
<% if @user.habits.any? %>
<h2>Habit Challenges (<%= @user.habits.count %>)</h2>
    <%= render @habits %>
<% end %>

<% if @user.valuations.any? %>
<h2>Values (<%= @user.valuations.count %>)</h2>
    <%= render @valuations %>
<% end %>

<% if @user.goals.any? %>
<h2>Current Goals (<%= @user.goals.unaccomplished.count %>)</h2>
    <%= render @unaccomplished_goals %>
<% end %>

<% if @user.goals.any? %>
<h2>Accomplished Goals (<%= @user.goals.accomplished.count %>)</h2>
    <%= render @accomplished_goals %>
<% end %>

<% if @user.quantifieds.any? %>
<h2>Stats: Monthly Average (<%= @user.quantifieds.count %>)</h2>
    <%= render @averaged_quantifieds %>
<% end %>

<% if @user.quantifieds.any? %>
<h2>Stats: Instances (<%= @user.quantifieds.count %>)</h2>
    <%= render @instance_quantifieds %>
<% end %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @habits = @user.habits.all
  @valuations = @user.valuations.all
  @accomplished_goals = @user.goals.accomplished.all
  @unaccomplished_goals = @user.goals.unaccomplished.all
  @averaged_quantifieds = @user.quantifieds.averaged.all
  @instance_quantifieds = @user.quantifieds.instance.all
end
```

As you can see by the picture if I create 3 habits, 3 tables of habits will show. If I create 4, 5, so on the same thing happens. The same goes for the rest, like with values (@valuations) 12 repetitions are being created.

[image]

habits/_habit.html.erb

```html
<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->
<div id="valuations" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>HABITS</b></h4></div>

  <!-- Table -->
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Level</th>
      <th>Left</th>
      <th>Strike</th>
      <th>Trigger</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      <th>Target</th>
      <th>Reward</th>
      <th>Days</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @habits.each do |challenged| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= challenged.current_level %></td>
        <td>
        <%= link_to edit_habit_path(challenged) do %>
        <%= [params[:missed]].flatten.length %>
        <% end %></td>
        <td><%= challenged.trigger %></td>
        <td class="category">
          <b><%= raw challenged.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></b>
        </td>
        <td><%= challenged.target %></td>
        <td class= "committed">
          <%= challenged.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.join ', ' %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas? I'm baffled.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? Can you post an example screenshot?

Comment: Update the picture to highlight the problem area please.

Comment: @AntarrByrd ignore the sidebar. It says habits 3 times. It should just say habits 1 time.

Comment: @RubyonRailsBeginner, update your partial according to my answer, it will fix your problem. The thing is, you are iterating over collections again in your partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<h2>Habit Challenges (<%= @habits.count %>)</h2>
<%= render @habits %>

<h2>Values (<%= @valuations.count %>)</h2>
<%= render @valuations %>

<h2>Current Goals (<%= @unaccomplished_goals.count %>)</h2>
<%= render @unaccomplished_goals %>

<h2>Accomplished Goals (<%= @accomplished_goals.count %>)</h2>
<%= render @accomplished_goals %>

<h2>Stats: Monthly Average (<%= @averaged_quantifieds.count %>)</h2>
<%= render @averaged_quantifieds %>

<h2>Stats: Instances (<%= @instance_quantifieds.count %>)</h2>
<%= render @instance_quantifieds %>
```

Change your show action:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @habits = @user.habits
  @valuations = @user.valuations
  @accomplished_goals = @user.goals.accomplished
  @unaccomplished_goals = @user.goals.unaccomplished
  @averaged_quantifieds = @user.quantifieds.averaged
  @instance_quantifieds = @user.quantifieds.instance
end
```

Change your partial, stop iterating over `@habits` again:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><%= habit.current_level %></td>
    <td><%= link_to edit_habit_path(habit) do %>
      <%= [params[:missed]].flatten.length %><% end %>
    </td>
    <td><%= habit.trigger %></td>
    <td class="category"><b><%= raw habit.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %></b></td>
    <td><%= habit.target %></td>
    <td class= "committed"><%= habit.committed.map { |d| d.titleize[0,3] }.join ', ' %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Update**:

Another way around, which will only repeat `tbody` (as per your request).

```
<h2>Habit Challenges (<%= @habits.count %>)</h2>
<%= render partial: 'habit', locals: {habits: @habits} %>
```

Then change your habit partial:

```
<% habits.each do |habit| %>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    ...
    ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No luck. I don't think count is the root of the problem because if I remove it from the view the repetitions still occur.

Comment: Updated my answer, can you try it? And if it fails, please update your post with full-size error screen-shot link.

Comment: Still no luck Sharvy. There is no error per se. I added a screen shot of what it looks like in my browser.

Comment: Could you please add the habit partial ?

Comment: @RubyonRailsBeginner, could you please update your show action?

Comment: Updated quested. Thanks!

Comment: Updated it Sharvy with your code but still didn't work. weird

Comment: @RubyonRailsBeginner, change your habit partial.

Comment: Sharvy is there a way to easily jump from this to where I can iterate within the habit so I can keep the `<thead>` and not have the `<thead>` repeat itself?

Comment: @RubyonRailsBeginner, see the `update` section of my post, hope it will ease your life. :)

Comment: Yes it does Sharvy thanks again =] And I like the quotes you choose on blog/profile. Makes you think.

Answer (score 0):

Are they part of the same controller? If so, call the partial without the variable...

```
<% if @user.habits.any? %>
<h2>Habit Challenges (<%= @user.habits.count %>)</h2>
    <%= render 'habits' %>
<% end %>
```

If not, call the partial with a local variable:

```
<% if @user.habits.any? %>
<h2>Habit Challenges (<%= @user.habits.count %>)</h2>
    <%= render 'habits', :locals => {:habits => @habits} %>
<% end %>
```

If that's the case, you have to change the partial to stop using @ based variable for @habits.

Comment: I added your code creativereason but it didn't fix anything :(

Comment: just updated, I still think the variables is the problem. Look again at the link @SteveTurczyn posted. You call partials by name, not by variable.

Comment: @creativereason, when you render a collection and pass the collection name instead of partial name, rails finds a partial for that collections, which is conventionally singular form of that collection name.

Comment: Thanks. Not a convention I've ever used, but as you mention @RubyonRailsBeginner is iterating twice.

Answer (score 0):

That's the normal behavour if you render a collection of objects. A partial for each object in the collection is rendered.

Look at section 3.4.5 of the guides.rubyonrails.org on layouts and rendering...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

The habit partial should probably be edited to show only what you want to show per element in the collection. If it is currently showing only the information for the first element, then you may not be passing the object correctly to the partial. See section 3.4.6 in the above document.